# spark - application returns different results based on different executor memory?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am noticing some peculiar behaviour, i have spark job which reads the data and does some grouping ordering and join and creates an output file.

The issue is when I run the same job on yarn with memory more than what the environment has eg the cluster has 50 GB and i submit spark-submit with close to 60 GB executor and 4gb driver memory. 
My results gets decreased seems like one of the data partitions or tasks are lost while processing.

```
driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 4g --num-executors 12
```

I also notice the warning message on driver -

```
WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
```

but when i run with limited executors and memory example 15GB, it works and i get exact rows/data. no warning message.

```
driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g --num-executors 4
```

any suggestions are we missing some settings on cluster or anything?
Please note my job completes successfully in both the cases.
 I am using spark version 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is meaningless (except maybe for debugging) - the plan is larger when there are more executors involved and the warning is that it is too big to be converted into a string. if you need it you can set `spark.debug.maxToStringFields` to a larger number (as suggested in the warning message)

Comment: my concern is not the warning message. The issue is the data partition/ task is lost. we are getting less rows when we run with more memory, same code if we execute with less than it works fine.

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior in spark 2.2 (I did see a bug in a 1.x that has similar symptoms - which is why the guids in the filenames were added) but it might be that when Yarn allocates the extra executor(s) (since you try to have more than the available memory) it somehow gets the same id and overwrite an existing file - if this is the problem you should see fewer files in the first run.

Comment: i see less data few lines less i data.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to check or validate if the same id is getting overridden?

Comment: in that case, you'd have fewer files